# Keeping an Object from moving beyond a certain point

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Im am making a game in sprite kit that requires the user to move the player across the x axis to catch things. I am trying to make it impossible for the player to move off the screen because that looks bad. I have tried to do this with an if statement saying if it moves past a certain point teleport it back to the correct point but am not sure how to do this. That might be the right way to do this but i'm not sure. Please tell / show me what I should do to make this work. I will post the code below.

```
import SpriteKit



struct physicsCatagory {
    static let person : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let Ice : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let IceTwo : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let IceThree : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let Score : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
}


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    var timeOfLastSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    var timePerSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 1.2
    var scorenumber = Int()
    var lifenumber = Int()
    var SpeedNumber : Double = 0.5
    var person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person1")
    let Score = SKSpriteNode()
    var ScoreLable = SKLabelNode()
    let BackGround = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "BackGround")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)

        lifenumber = 0
        SpeedNumber = 1

        BackGround.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        BackGround.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        BackGround.zPosition = -5
        self.addChild(BackGround)


         Score.size = CGSize(width: 648, height: 1)
        Score.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: -90)
        Score.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Score.size)
        Score.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Score.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Score.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.Score
        Score.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        Score.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Score.color = SKColor.blueColor()
        self.addChild(Score)


        person.zPosition = 1
        person.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/10)
        person.setScale(0.32)
        person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 50))
        person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.person
        person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.dynamic = false




        ScoreLable = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Zapfino")
        ScoreLable.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 1000)
        ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
        ScoreLable.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        ScoreLable.fontSize = 100
        ScoreLable.fontName = "Zapfino "
        self.addChild(ScoreLable)





        self.addChild(person)





    }




     func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            let firstBody = contact.bodyA
            let secondBody = contact.bodyB


        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person{

           scorenumber++

            if scorenumber == 20 {

              timePerSpawn = 1.0

            }

            if scorenumber == 40{
                timePerSpawn = 0.89

            }
            if scorenumber == 60{

                timePerSpawn = 0.6
            }
            if scorenumber == 80{

                timePerSpawn = 0.5
            }

            if scorenumber == 100{

                timePerSpawn = 0.4
            }

            if scorenumber == 120{

                timePerSpawn = 0.3
            }



            ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
            CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Person: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)


        }

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree ||
            firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score{
                lifenumber++

                if lifenumber == 1{
                    //person.texture
                    person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower#2")
                }

                if lifenumber == 2{
            person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower #3")

        }
                if lifenumber == 3{
                    self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())

                }


        }
    }



    func CollisionWithPerson (Ice: SKSpriteNode, Person: SKSpriteNode){

      Person.removeFromParent()

    }



    func spawnThirdIce(){

        var Ice = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ice")
        Ice.zPosition = 2
        Ice.setScale(0.9)
        Ice.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ice.size)
        Ice.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Ice.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.person | physicsCatagory.Score
        Ice.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Ice.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
        let MaxValue = self.size.width - 20
        let SpawnPoint =  UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
        Ice.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
        self.addChild(Ice)

        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-85, duration: 2.0)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        Ice.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action,actionDone]))


    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            }
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
            let ammountDragged = location.x - previousTouch.x


            person.position.x += ammountDragged











        }
    }




    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        if (currentTime - timeOfLastSpawn > timePerSpawn) {
            spawnThirdIce()
            self.timeOfLastSpawn = currentTime
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948028/how-to-give-screen-edge-a-physics-body

Comment: You could look into SKConstraint. Create a `+positionX:` constraint, and assign it to an SKNode's `constraints` property.

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like:

```
    if node.position.x > scene.width {
        node.position.x = scene.width
    }

    if node.position.x < 0 {
        node.position.x = 0
}
```